# Why [[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; cause UIBarButtonItem's tintColor failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I can set the UIBarButtonItem's tintColor success

```
UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction)];
backItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
```

After I call below code in AppDelegate will fail set UIBarButtonItem's tintColor

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: where you put that code for bar button item , and  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` call first before any method so i don't think so it creates problem

Comment: Try [UIView appearance] instead of [UITextView appearance]

Comment: I have report a bug for apple in the detail. https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem